# Best practice in upgrading from instant app to full app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have yet to find a clear and straight forward solution to letting the user download the full app, as he's using the instant app.

There are docs regarding how and where to show the install button, but none tell how exactly to make the user download it.

Should we just link to the store and let the user click Install, or is there a better approach directly within the instant app .... somehow?! Some sort of ... "one click direct install"

Cheers !

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "but none tell how exactly to make the user download it.", besides the install buttons in instant app?
When you prompt user to install full app from instant app, you need to use Material Design "get app" icon and the label "install" for the installation button (https://play.google.com/about/other-programs/offering-app/).

Comment: yeah, that's what I found out myself, but what's the exact functionality behind the get_app icon ? Do i just use an intent to open my app in the google play app or how do i actually have the user install the app?

Comment: I'm 99% sure the redirect to google play is the way to go, but I'm hoping and thinking there might be another way, easier/faster way. dunno ...

Comment: For that you need to use showInstallPrompt(), it opens a dialog in instant app that prompts user to install your full app.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantApps#showInstallPrompt(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

For instant > installed app upgrade use [showInstallPrompt()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantApps#showInstallPrompt(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20java.lang.String)), it opens a dialog in instant app that prompts user to install your full app.

Also, take a look at the guidelines [here](https://play.google.com/about/other-programs/offering-app/):

> When offering installation, developers must:
>    - Use the Material Design "get app" icon and the label "install" for the installation button.
>    - Not have more than 2-3 implicit installation prompts in their instant app.
>    - Not use a banner or other ad-like technique for presenting an installation prompt to users.

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising, but it seems it doesn't find the method in the class. This is the only thing I've got in there ... http://puu.sh/CG7vP/33b0104cfa.png 
Ideas ?!